# What websites support two factor authentication?

Tags: security

Is there a central listing of websites that support two factor authentication, and which two-factor methods they support?

Comment: Technically, all OpenID consumer sites support it indirectly (Google is an OpenID provider).

Comment: This question may not have seemed relevant at the time, but it is certainly relevant for today's internet.  The question should either be reopened or at least moved to a different stack exchange site.  (Modern answer: http://twofactorauth.org/)

Answer (score 1):

That isn't something companies post to the open world. That's like asking who all are using RSA Tokens. Well, there are too many to list. The two of them are the same thing with different names. It's becoming more and more common for companies to use this method to add another layer of security. For example, the gaming industry is pushing it on its MMO customers to help prevent their account from being hacked.

Comment: [This](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/03/after-n-hijack-software-engineer-starts-two-factor-authentication-directory/) Ars article reminded me of this question (and answer).  In today's internet it _is_ something companies post to the open world, and it's something users expect to be able to find out.